# What is the meaning of "morality is a question of time"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

> I  never  succumbed  to  that  or  to  any  of  her  many  other  lewd  temptations,  but  she  did  not 
>   believe  in the purity of  my principles. Morality, too,  **is a question of time**, she would say with a malevolent smile, 
>   you'll see.  - Garcia Marquez, Gabriel, Memories of my melancholy whores, Ch. 1

What is the meaning of question of time in the above paragraph?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @KF2 notes, sometimes that which seems immoral in one time seems not so immoral in another.  The context of that passage is that at the age of 90, the character decides to give himself the gift of a young girl.

> The year I turned ninety, I wanted to give myself the gift of a night of wild love with an adolescent virgin. I thought of Rosa Cabarcas, the owner of an illicit house who would inform her good clients when she had a new girl available. *I never succumbed to that or to any of her many other lewd temptations* [his morals stopped him], but she did not believe in the purity of my principles. *Morality, too, is a question of time, she would say* with a malevolent smile, you’ll see. She was a little younger than I, and I hadn’t heard anything about her for so many years that she very well might have died. But after the first ring I recognized the voice on the phone, and with no preambles I fired at her: “Today’s the day.” [Time had changed his morals.]

Answer (score 3):

In this case "question" means matter or consideration.  So in that sentence, morality is not something concrete, it is a matter of time, for example something might be moral today, but not tomorrow or in ten years because people's values and beliefs change.